# Is there an option to set up autoscaling for PostgreSQL on Google Cloud?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, autoscaling

We need to manage high load for our application on PostgreSQL database. According to our research autoscaling is supported only for Cloud Spanner database. 
In case we missed something, does anyone know whether there is an autoscaling support for PostgreSQL? If not, are there any plans to support it in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Do not exist the autoscaling for PostegreSQL.

You can make reed replicas, that could distribuite the workload, only for reading the DB.

The other solution is the Autoscaling but only works with managed instance groups.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/